# How to ensure that all the code in a try code block executes or fails completely

Tags: c#

please is there any way to ensure that all the code in a **c# try code block executes or fails completely.**

Comment: are you asking for a transactional code, or do you just want to know whether the code executed?

Comment: Well, every code either executes or fails. The only other option is an infinite loop. If your question is "how to undo the effects of failed execution", then I'm afraid there's no language construct to do it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as making your code transactional, there is no way to make sure that everything inside a `try` block will execute together.

instead, in your `catch` block you'll need to restore the state somehow, or rollback changes.

I'd suggest storing whatever important is important on memory (or disk if you're worried about the application going completely down) and then restore the state information in your catch statement.

Comment: Sorry i didn't clarify before, what am asking is that i have a linq code that makes two insertion into the database using entity framework. Now the first insertion returns a primary key that is used for the second insertion. Now Table A has a one to many relationship with Table B. What am asking is that if Table B insertion fails, Is there any way to undo the table A insertion

Comment: @Cizaphil there's a lot of literature regarding rolling back your database to a previous state.  I'm not enough of a database guru give you advice that I'd feel good about, but you can use google to see what you can find.  I'm sure that there's a built-in way.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm guessing, you've got multiple things going on in your `try` block.  Something like:

```
try
{
     Func1();
     Func2();
}
```

Now, in this example, you'd want both functions to either pass or fail.  So, if `Func1()` fails, you still want it to call `Func2()`.  The problem is that if `Func1()` fails, then the block fails.  There's just no way around that.  And if the first part fails, there's no point in continuing on, so `Func2()` won't even be called.  If this is indeed the case, you would either have to use an `if` statement, or a `try catch` for each function.

Comment: No what i want is that if Func1() passes, i did want Func2() to pass or to roll back the  side effect of Func1(). Or to put it in another way, if Func2() fails, i did want the effect of Func1() to be rolled back.